# How to write attributes in points or instances created by geometry nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I created some instances using geometry nodes, and now I want to write new attributes in these points or instances and use them in the geometry nodes.

I tried these codes to write attributes in vertices (because I don't know how to get instances and points), although 'attr' appears in the spreadsheet, they still cannot be saved to the geometry nodes. Once any operations are done in the geometric nodes (I guess  the original model is updated), these written data will disappear

```
import bpy

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
obj = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
mesh = obj.data

if mesh.attributes.find('attr') == -1:
    mesh.attributes.new('attr', 'INT', 'POINT')

i = 0
while i < len(mesh.vertices):
    mesh.attributes['attr'].data[i].value = i
    print(mesh.attributes['attr'].data[i].value)
    i += 1
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's totally normal, because GN generates new mesh for the tree for every "update". Maybe you tell us what you wanna achieve as end goal? instead of asking for technical details, so we might come up with a "better" easier solution?

Comment: Thank you for your help Chris！I read the order of points, generate an index list, and used AI to create a value for each point (for example, I told AI that I want all points is butterfly，1 for butterfly， 2 for ant), and wanted to return this value back to the geometry node and instantiate them.@Chris

Comment: You need to apply the modifier for it to work. Or use geometry nodes to process the attribute values

Comment: Are there other global variables (geometry node can read) can be used to store this data？
My current solution is copy an evaluated mesh in code and attach the instantiated geometry node to it. However, this is too complex, I hope there is a more direct method